# Is it correct to say "I weeded the wheat"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

We often say "**to weed + a ground**", for example, “**I weeded the garden/flower bed…**”.

Do we say “**to weed + a kind of plant**”, for example, “**I weeded the wheat/flowers…**”?

This is from [Google book](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=rC9sreZyyU8C&pg=PA452&lpg=PA452&dq=%22weeded%20the%20wheat%22&source=bl&ots=zRpfwVB5am&sig=ACfU3U0stJ8dk7hQ2gPzD1IKnFzUNcowlw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibvcL_-sH1AhXDSWwGHdv-C5oQ6AF6BAgOEAM#v=onepage&q=%22weeded%20the%20wheat%22&f=false) "**I had weeded the wheat in the Spring**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* say "**I weeded the wheat**," and the meaning will be understood, however the more common construction is "**I weeded the field** [*of wheat*]."  You can see a comparison of usage in this [Google nGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=weeded%20the%20wheat%2Cweeded%20the%20field&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cweeded%20the%20wheat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cweeded%20the%20field%3B%2Cc0).  I would discourage using the less common form, but would certainly not forbid it.

Regarding "**weeding the flowers**", this is also a [commonly used expression](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=weeded%20the%20flowers%2Cweeding%20the%20flowers&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cweeded%20the%20flowers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cweeding%20the%20flowers%3B%2Cc0), especially as "the flowers" is a common way to say "the garden/flower bed", which you already know is often used with the verb "weed" in its various forms.

Comment: Could also say *"I weeded the wheat field"*.